# Generalised inclusion-exclusion problem

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving, inclusion-exclusion

I'm having a lot of problem defining my sets for a inclusion/exclusion problem:

**How many positive integers below 10 000 are not perfect square and are not a power of 3,4,5... of an integer**

So first I let $$P_i = \{n\in \mathbb{Z} | 1\leq n \leq 9999, n = k^i, k\in \mathbb {Z}\}$$ for $i\geq 2$

But from here I get a bit confused.

We use the notation $N(P_i)$ for the number of elements in the set $ P_i$ . But I figured it would mean that $N(P_i) = \lfloor\sqrt[i]{9999}\rfloor$ where the greatest $i$ would be $13$. Would I be wrong? I used the fact that $\lfloor\sqrt[i]{9999}\rfloor \geq 2$.

Moreover, after I sum all the floor function for $1\leq i \leq 13$ how do I define the intersections? For example, if an integer is a power of $2$ and $3$ how could I define the set of all the positive integers below $9999$ that have both these properties?

And finally, what would be the underlying logic for $N(P_i) = \lfloor\sqrt[i]{9999}\rfloor$. Is it that the greatest integer such that it  is the $i^{th}$ power of an integer  $k$ would be that one, cause all subsequent one when elevated to the $j \geq i+1$ power would be over 9999...

I think my question about my confusion is confusing but if someone could help me to define my sets and find their cardinality I would be so thankful.

Thank you

Comment: If a number is simultaneously a perfect $n$'th power and a perfect $m$'th power, then that implies that the number must be a perfect $\text{lcm}(n,m)$'th power.  In you specific example, if it is a perfect square and a perfect cube, then that implies that it must be a perfect sixth power.

Comment: You can make your life easier by noting that all perfect fourthpowers, sixth powers, eighth powers, etc... are all also perfect squares.  Similarly for others, so you can reduce the list of exponents to just prime exponents.